# How can I read/write files in Android/iOs devices subdirectories using Cordova File Plugin?

Tags: android, ios, file, cordova, plugins

I'm trying this code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {   
    alert(fileSystem.root.toURL());

    fileSystem.root.getDirectory('myDir', { create: true }, function (myDirEntry) {
        alert(myDirEntry.toURL());

        myDirEntry.getDirectory('mySubDir', { create: true }, function (mySubDirEntry) {
            alert(mySubDirEntry.toURL());
            alert('/myDir/mySubDir creation is done');

        }, getDirectoryError);
    }, getDirectoryError);      
}, requestFileSystemError);
```

As a result of executing it on a Samsung SM-G318ML, Kernel version 3.10.17-983426, I got alerts showing the following messages:

```
file:data/data/com.mydomain.myapp/files/files/    
file:data/data/com.mydomain.myapp/files/files/myDir
file:data/data/com.mydomain.myapp/files/files/myDir/mySubDir
/myDir/mySubDir creation is done.
```

Neverthless, when I look in my device's file system I have no desired directories created... besides it a strange directory, called .mtp, was created, void, at system root.

My goal is create and read files to/from /com.mydomain.mayapp/files/profile/images directory. My code is based on a sample provided (in the end of the page) in  [Sample Link Followed](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/README.md) ; I am using Cordova.File plugin, version 4.1.0, in an Intel XDK hybrid app project.  
I have the necessary `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission defined.

Can someone point me in the right direction? All advices are welcome... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Another document that I found very useful is here:[cordova-plugin-file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file)

according to this document:

**cordova.file.dataDirectory** - Persistent and private data storage within the application's sandbox using internal memory (**on Android, if you need to use external memory, use .externalDataDirectory**). On iOS, this directory is not synced with iCloud (use .syncedDataDirectory). (iOS, Android, BlackBerry 10, windows)

Answer (score 0):

The directories that you are writting, are inside data/data folders, which belongs only to your app, and can't be accessed thought the device file system.

If you want to use public folders, check this table

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#android-file-system-layout

And choose a folder that don't be private.

For example: externalApplicationStorageDirectory

Happy coding!

Comment: Ok Del... thanks, but how can I get access to read/write in externalApplicationStorageDirectory? I ask you that because requestFileSystem function allways return a pointer to data/data/... And one more question: am I forbidden to write in dataDirectory... why?